# Clean URL without filetype

Tags: url-rewriting

I want to make my url site clean. http://sample.com/about-me

This my code:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php
```

But I check still can access `http://sample.com/about-me.php`. How to make my site just can access `http://sample.com/about-me`, so `http://sample.com/about-me.php` will be redirect permanent to `http://sample.com/about-me`???

I think this technique is good for SEO because canonicalization need just one url, if use two url can be access, I think its not good for SEO and can make search engine confused. Isn't right ???

Thank you

Comment: Search engines only see (find) the urls fed into them, by sitemaps or links on other pages. So if you only publish one url only that one will be indexed by search engines.

Answer (score 0):

As I already commented above: search engines only see (find) the urls fed into them, by sitemaps or links on other pages. So if you only publish one url only that one will be indexed by search engines. So I don't really see a point in explicitly blocking browsers.

Just rewrite the requests like this and all is fine:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L,QSA,R=301]
```

That external redirection makes sure that browsers are really redirected visibly, so it is more likely that only the desired url will be used as link in other pages.

Comment: I stripped that senseless blocking rule from the answer.